# Галерея изображений

Tags: php, html, javascript

Есть вот такая вот галерея: [код](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=406), [демо](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les406/example/demo.php).

Спрашиваю одно, возможно ли, чтобы в галерее выводилось, например, по 20 картинок, а все оставшиеся изображения переводились на другую страницу. То есть, все картинки делились по 20 шт и на страницы, по которым они будут выводиться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно всё :) но приведенный скрипт для этого придется допиливать.

Нужна листалка (pager), нужны стили для нее, нужна обработка ее в скрипте. Сейчас скрипт довольно примитивен, выводит все картинки из каталога по четыре штуки в ряд (прямо как в поговорке).

Нет особого смысла обсуждать, что нужно переделать — уж чего-чего, а галерей с использованием jQuery написано тысячи штук. Вот, например, симпатичная [галерея с листалкой](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

Да это же классический [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/), заезженный уже до дыр. Никакие картинки в ряд он не выводит, вы можете изменять хтмл структуру превьюшек как вам захочеться (хоть по 10 штук в два ряда), только главное выводить ссылку, которая в href содержит адрес на большую картинку, а в саму ссылку вставлять картинку-превью. Скрипт начинает работать только после клика на изображение.

Comment: Все что вы мне кидаете это не то.
Я ищу скрипт чтобы сканировал папку на сервере и выводил картинки с делением их на страницы.

Comment: Мы вам ничего не кидаем, скрипт который бы сканировал папку на сервере вы не найдете. Js это клиентский язык и на сервере он не работает, им можно только послать запрос на сервер, чтобы там произошла выборка нужных картинок и отправка их обратно в ответе. Вы можете на сервере генерировать страницы с постраничной навигацией, на которую выводить картинки в нужном количестве и подключать скрипт. Js разбиение на страницы использовать нельзя, потому что надо сначала загрузить все картинки с сервера, а потом скрипт только будет их обрабатывать (если картинок будет очень много это может затянуться).

Comment: > скрипт который бы сканировал папку на сервере вы не найдете.

Собственно, он у автора топика уже есть. А с хорошей клиентской галереей нет необходимости даже листалку на стороне сервера делать.

Comment: makregistr, будьте внимательней. Сканер сервера уже есть в 1м сообщении...
Надо пробывать классический Lightbox сделать со сканером...

Comment: нет там никакого сканера сервера, грузятся все картинки, он выводит определенное количество на первой, а все лишнее прячет display="none", а потом их показывает. Это демо страница и на ней все нормально работает, но представьте сайт и в галерее очень много изображений. Они все должны загрузиться и только потом скрипт их всех посчитает, спрячет лишние и будет показывать нужное количество.

Comment: спасибо. Решил попробывать сделать на SQL. Подсказал хорошоий человек.